# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0

Tags: android, firebase

Did everything according to FB documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) but
I still get the following error when compiling:

```
Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0
```

My SDK manager says that everything is up to date:

```
Google Play services Rev. 33 installed
Google Repository Rev. 35 installed
```

This is my build.gradle content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    // Google APIs
    // Note: Avoid compiling the entire play-services package.
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'

    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0' //<-- CAUSING TROUBLE
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my root level build.gradle content:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Why isn't it compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'` instead of `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'`

Answer (score 7):

The answer @Lorenzo Quiroli provided will probably help you, you need the same version of Firebase and Google Play Services.

In my case, I had everything set to 9.6.0 but was still getting the error. I solved it by updating to the latest google-play-services and google repository through the SDK Manager:

[image]

Now I know this won't help you because you had already updated these, but it might help someone else.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the same version of Firebase and Google Play Services. So if you want to update to Firebase 9.6.0 SDK you should also update the other dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.0'
```